# Qt: huge scrollable sub-menu loses items

Tags: css, qt, submenu

**Updated to add:**

I have fixed this, after a fashion. First, I tried calling `MySubmenu -> clear()` and rebuilding the sub-menu whenever the parent menu was clicked. Surprisingly, this didn't work. So I brought in the big guns: `delete MySubmenu` followed by `MySubmenu = new QMenu (MyMainWindow)` and rebuilding the sub-menu. It works now, without much noticeable delay. So I'm happy, I suppose.

**Original question:**

I have a sub-menu with about 1000 items in it (it's a list of C functions in a debugger). By default, Qt displays the sub-menu in columns, but this sub-menu is too big to fit on the screen, and I have no way to access the items that don't fit.

So I made the sub-menu scrollable, using a style sheet:

```
MySubmenu -> setStyleSheet ("* { menu-scrollable: 1 }") ;
```

It looks like this:

[image: Big menu]

Note the scroll buttons at the top and bottom. But now if I select an item (PopRecordLength in this example), then the next time I open the sub-menu, all items above PD_DecryptCommand have disappeared:

[image: Bad menu]

The scroll button at the top has disappeared (the little line you can see is an underscore from what used to be the previous item.) And if I scroll down to the bottom, there is a large empty space. The total size of the sub-menu hasn't changed, but the items above PD_DecryptCommand have disappeared off the top, and I can't access them with mouse or keyboard.

However...I have just discovered, in the process of preparing this post, that if I click on this large empty space, the sub-menu disappears, but the next time I open it, it has been restored to its original state. So there is a work-around. But it's not very friendly.

Is this a bug in Qt? Or am I not setting the style sheet correctly?

Comment: Hey @TonyK, did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @SirJames: No, I never did. I do it properly now, with a dialog box.

Comment: You create a scroll list with a dialog box? Does it behave similarly? I ask because I am doing something similar in PySide but generally have 80-200 menuItems.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, since you have so many items that the menu takes the whole screen height, when you select an item its height increases a bit and the scroll button on top gets out of view.

I would try to connect the `triggered` signal of the menu with the `update` slot in order to get the menu repainted every time an action has been triggered

```
connect(MySubmenu , SIGNAL(triggered(QAction*), MySubmenu , SLOT(update()));
```

You could also try changing the max-height of your menu (`max-height` stylesheet property).

Comment: The scroll button is still there. But it doesn't appear in the second screen shot because the menu is as far up as it can go. If I scroll down, it appears as normal. I tried your suggestion to connect the `triggered` signal to the `update` slot, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry, not really an answer to your question, but do you really think it's a good idea to put 1000 items into a menu? The usability of this is just terrible. You should find a better way to present so many actions to the user, such as alphabetical submenus ("p" -> "PopRecordLength", "PopShort" ... ). This would also solve your problem with the menu.

Comment: I reckoned I might get one or two responses like this! But my users will typically have to deal with 20-50 items. I myself am the only user who will have to deal with so many items, and I would be happy with a (working) 1000-item sub-menu.

Comment: A 50 item menu is still a whopping GUI blooper!  And 'typically' implies that there will be users who get a lot more.  You probably have found a bug, but since you are utterly abusing the design of a submenu - it's unsurprising it doesn't work.